# Simple schedulling in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to build a really simple schedulling program in Prolog. The main objective is to assign a person on each different shift, according to their restrictions. **Edit: I have more than 10 unique shifts to calculate and more than 20 people** So, given these facts:

```
% shifts
shift(s1).
shift(s2).
shift(s3).
% ...

% person and shift preferences
m(linda, s1).
m(bruce, s1).
m(bruce, s2).
m(bruce, s3).
m(ariel, s2).
m(ariel, s3).

possible(L):-shift(S), m(M,S), L = [S,M].

allpossibleshifts(L):-findall(A,possible(A),DL), sort(DL, L).
```

Output:

```
L = [[s1, bruce], [s1, linda], [s2, ariel], [s2, bruce], [s3, ariel], [s3, bruce]]
```

As you can see, this returns all compatible assignments. I need to get a whole solution, with a single assignment per shift, honoring preferences. These two, for instance, are good examples of a desired output:

```
L = [[t1, linda], [t2, bruce], [t3, ariel]]
L = [[t1, linda], [t2, ariel], [t3, bruce]]
```

Comment: In ... `L = [T,M]`, what's `T`? It's a singleton variable. So not really defined in the rule. Do you really mean, `[S,M]`?

Comment: Sorry. T is S. I'll edit it